# How do I position an SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, navbar

I have an SVG in a navbar that's supposed to go to the right when hovered. The HTML and CSS is below:

```css
.logo {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--text-secondary);
  background: var(--bg-secondary);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.3ch;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo svg {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.logo-text {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.navbar .logo-text {
  display: none;
}

.navbar:hover .logo svg {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<li class="logo">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">
    <span class="link-text logo-text">ELC</span>
    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fad" data-icon="angle-double-right" height="50" width="50" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-angle-double-right fa-w-14 fa-5x">
            <g class="fa-group">
              <path
                fill="currentColor"
                d="M224 273L88.37 409a23.78 23.78 0 0 1-33.8 0L32 386.36a23.94 23.94 0 0 1 0-33.89l96.13-96.37L32 159.73a23.94 23.94 0 0 1 0-33.89l22.44-22.79a23.78 23.78 0 0 1 33.8 0L223.88 239a23.94 23.94 0 0 1 .1 34z"
                class="fa-secondary"
              ></path>
              <path
                fill="currentColor"
                d="M415.89 273L280.34 409a23.77 23.77 0 0 1-33.79 0L224 386.26a23.94 23.94 0 0 1 0-33.89L320.11 256l-96-96.47a23.94 23.94 0 0 1 0-33.89l22.52-22.59a23.77 23.77 0 0 1 33.79 0L416 239a24 24 0 0 1-.11 34z"
                class="fa-primary"
              ></path>
            </g>
          </svg>
  </a>
</li>
```

Instead of going to the right when hovered on, it goes to the left instead, as shown below:
[image: Navbar]

I want the arrow to go the very right of the black space, but instead it goes to the left and covers the text. How can I change this?

Comment: Looks like maybe you did not include all your HTML, there is no div with the class of navbar in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `display-flex` and `justify-content: space-between` on the `<a>` element for this.

I also commented out the absolute positioning of `.logo-text`.

I also added `list-style-type: none;` to `.logo` to get rid of the bullet point.

```css
.logo {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--text-secondary);
  background: var(--bg-secondary);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.3ch;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.logo svg {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.logo-text {
  /* display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem; */
  padding-left: 1rem;                     /* added to shift text right */
  transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.navbar .logo-text {
  display: none;
}

.navbar:hover .logo svg {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

a {                                  /* added */
  display: flex;                     /* added */
  justify-content: space-between;    /* added */
}                                    /* added */
```

```html
<li class="logo">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">
    <span class="link-text logo-text">ELC</span>
    <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fad" data-icon="angle-double-right" height="50" width="50" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" class="svg-inline--fa fa-angle-double-right fa-w-14 fa-5x">
            <g class="fa-group">
              <path
                fill="currentColor"
                d="M224 273L88.37 409a23.78 23.78 0 0 1-33.8 0L32 386.36a23.94 23.94 0 0 1 0-33.89l96.13-96.37L32 159.73a23.94 23.94 0 0 1 0-33.89l22.44-22.79a23.78 23.78 0 0 1 33.8 0L223.88 239a23.94 23.94 0 0 1 .1 34z"
                class="fa-secondary"
              ></path>
              <path
                fill="currentColor"
                d="M415.89 273L280.34 409a23.77 23.77 0 0 1-33.79 0L224 386.26a23.94 23.94 0 0 1 0-33.89L320.11 256l-96-96.47a23.94 23.94 0 0 1 0-33.89l22.52-22.59a23.77 23.77 0 0 1 33.79 0L416 239a24 24 0 0 1-.11 34z"
                class="fa-primary"
              ></path>
            </g>
          </svg>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob Moll! One more thing, this probably has a really easy fix but the text is a little bit too much to the right like [this](https://i.imgur.com/0R93k9l.png). How can I make it go slightly more to the right, but not completely?

Comment: It's unclear as to whether you want the text or the arrows to be shifted slightly to the left or right. I am guessing that you want the text "ELC" to be moved slightly to the right. I added `padding-left: 1rem;` to `.logo-text` which shifts that text 1 rem to the right. Let me know if that works or clarify what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `padding-left: 1rem` shifted the text to the left, which is what I needed.